# Compiling C extensions for Python3 on CentOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos6

I need to write python interface wrappers around some C functions, which requires the Python.h header file. I want to make sure I get the correct Python.h.

I'm working in CentOS 6.6 and decided to use Python 3.4 so as to avoid using the OS's python distribution. Online sources suggest getting the correct Python.h from python34-devel , but this package is not available for Centos 6, even through the EPEL repository. Also, I was forced to compile and [install python from source](http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/), and this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/498393/python-devel-for-python-2-7-on-centos-6-4) seems to suggest python34-devel might not even be helpful in this case.

How do I find the right Python.h so that I can compile C libraries for my Python configuration?

thanks in advance

Comment: You should switch to Python 3.5 already, Python 3.4 is in "security-fix" mode already.

Comment: I'm all in favor of using the latest version, but the toolchain I am using is restricted to Python 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do things properly and make a complete installable package for your wrapper, with `setup.py`, then you do not even need to know the location of the includes; as your python3.4 executable would know their location.

Minimlly your `setup.py` could be something like

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

c_ext = Extension('mypackage._mymodule.c',
                  sources = ['mypackage/_mymodule.c'],
                  )

setup(name='mypackage',
      version='1.0',
      description='...',
      long_description='...',
      packages=['mypackage']
      ext_modules=[c_ext])
```

Then you would store your C extension sources in `mypackage/_mymodule.c`, and have `mypackage/__init__.py` or some python modules write nice wrappers to the C extension itself (as some things are just to tedious to do it in C); minimally this would do

```
from mypackage._mymodule import *
```

Now to install this extension, you'd just execute `python3.4 setup.py install` and it would automatically compile your extension using whatever include directory *and* compile-time options are appropriate for *that* installation, and install it into the `site-packages` directory.

Comment: I was able to replicate this and confirmed it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Max if you had any problems there, you can add a comment here so I will edit my answer appropriately.